# Virtualization software prototype?

Tags: java, virtual-machine, vmware, virtualization, kvm

I have a poc on Virtualization In the  prototype, i will make a central Java controller must be 
able to receive start / stop / status commands over an API and use KVM to start a VM, 
request its status and stop it.

**Functionality**

- The controller receives the command to start a VM over its API with a
  certain MAC address: /api/vm/start/
- It creates a Windows VM from a base image using the MAC address
  The booted VM reports back through the controller’s API
- The controller returns the current status of the VM by MAC address
  through its API:
  /api/vm/status/
- The controller receives the command to stop the VM and kills it:

  /api/vm/stop/

Can anyone suggest me how to start and best solutions to do that .

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The page

[KVM management tools](http://www.linux-kvm.org/page/Management_Tools)

has some candidates of KVM management tools that may provide libraries or even web services to accomplish your tasks. Maybe even the finer details of generating a new per machine SID when creating a Windows instance. For a POC you may start with virsh, because it is a commandline tool and therefor easy to play with.